# Unable to publish PoseStamped message

Tags: ros-melodic, posestamped, rospy, geometry-msgs, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish a `PoseStamped` message via a node running in Python. I am listening for this message on another tab in my terminal.

Python node:

```
import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

rospy.init_node("mynode")

goal_publisher = rospy.Publisher("move_base_simple/goal", PoseStamped, queue_size=5)

goal = PoseStamped()

goal.header.seq = 1
goal.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
goal.header.frame_id = "map"

goal.pose.position.x = 1.0
goal.pose.position.y = 2.0
goal.pose.position.z = 0.0

goal.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
goal.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
goal.pose.orientation.z = 0.0
goal.pose.orientation.w = 1.0

goal_publisher.publish(goal)

rospy.spin()
```

So this my order of doing things:

1. In the first tab of terminal run `roscore`
2. In the second tab run `rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal`
3. In the third tab run the Python node which publishes a message

However no message is printed in the 2nd tab. What am I doing wrong? I am not getting any error messages.

**EDIT**: If I add a small delay before the `goal_publisher.publish(goal)` line then the message gets published.

```
rospy.sleep(1)
goal_publisher.publish(goal)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306582/unable-to-publish-posestamped-message/) by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 512 on 2018-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> **EDIT**: If I add a small delay before the `goal_publisher.publish(goal)` line then the message gets published.

This is something that has come up many times and that makes me wonder whether we should add this to the wiki about Publishers and Subscibers in some form.

Setting up connections between publishers and subscibers *takes time*. Subscibers connect to publishers *directly*, not to the Master, nor does the Master buffer messages, so even if you start your subscriber *before* your publisher there is a non-zero amount of time needed for the two to connect.

If there are no connections, any message you publish will be dropped and won't reach anyone.

In your publisher program, you don't give any potentially interested subscribers any time to set up a connection, so it is most likely your `PoseStamped` message is dropped.

You have two options:

1. publish the message periodically (so that even if there are no subscribers *now*, they'll receive one of the later messages published to the topic). That may or may not be appropriate for what you're trying to do (ie: for some messages / interactions it doesn't make sense to duplicate the same message)
2. wait for subscribers to connect. With your `edit` you've already done that, but you did it *time based*. It's always nicer to do things *state based*, which in this case means: look at the nr of subscribers and if there is at least one (or any other number) *then* publish your message. You can use [Topic::get_num_connections](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Topic-class.html#get_num_connections) for that in `rospy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3